# How to name call directory in Java on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, file, directory, filepath

Sorry if this seems like a rudimentary question, but I couldn't seem to find any answers on it.

I have some java code that works fine on windows. In it, I have one line that says:

```
File dir = new File("F:\\some\\files\\here");
```

I'm running this code on a remote server on Linux, except now it's giving me issues. I changed the line to the following since I have no idea what the drive name is (I don't think this matters on Linux?):

```
File dir = new File("\\some\\files\\here");
```

There's no error on this line, but later on, I call

```
File[] data = dir.listFiles();
```

On my windows code this works fine, but on Linux it returns me a null object. I looked into it a bit further and it seems that my original code doesn't get me a directory back in Linux.

```
dir.isDirectory()
```

Returns `false` on the Linux code.

Anyone know what may be the issue? I've also tried using / instead of \ but same problem.

Some additional information:

I can access any parts of methods of dir fine, except for listFiles() or list(). One thing I've tried is doing dir.getParent().listFiles()[0]. getParent() should get me a directory no matter what, but again the listFiles() call gives me a null object and it also tells me that the result from getParent() is a file, not a directory.

Comment: unix systems have no drive letters, and use `/` for directory separators. you'd need to have `/some/files` e.g (`some` dir in the root of the filesystem, `files` below `some`, etc..

Comment: You are going to hard pressed to make something hard coded figure out where on different computers the directory you want lives. This question basically makes no sense. What if on another windows computer there was no `F:` drive?

Comment: *"I've also tried using / instead of \ but same problem."*  You seem like you're typing random strings into the source.  Use `file.separator` instead.

Comment: You may want to play with some other stuff too, like trying to query the files in the current directory through java code... that might give you more insight into your problem. Here's a reference for seeing the files: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/3-java-program-can-list-all-files-given-directory.html

Comment: @Andrew, I tried that and same problem. Another thing to note is that the directory initialization seems to work fine, I can call getName() and getPath(), except it's just that I can't get listFiles() to work properly. I think Linux is interpreting it as a file instead of a directory for some reason, even though I include no extension

Answer (score 0):

You should use File.separator.
This is a plataform-independent tool, so there won't be any problems building a path in either Windows nor Linux

Comment: And how, pray tell, will that figure out *on what drive* to look?

Comment: From "File" documentation: _The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\\'._

Comment: And ... how do you get `F:` from that instead of `C:`?

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know in the future, but it doesn't fix my issue. I think the first line is working fine, since I'm able to mess with the File however I want. It's just that I can't seem to get list() or listFiles() working. Now I think it's less of a path issue and more of a Linux is interpreting the File as a file rather than a directory.

Comment: @xhassassin: You really should read the Javadoc of `java.io.File`. `isDirectory()` returns `true` "if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory; `false` otherwise". So your directory might just not exist, because UNIX is unable to make use of your Windows-style path. That's also the reason why `listFiles()` returns `null`, which indicates that "if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."